# Lookahead Assertion JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to solve my problem with a regular expression, and I believe a lookahead assertion may be the best answer (or so I think), but I am not sure how to use them.

For the input example `int a = 5;` I would to grab the value of the int identifier, `5`, with a RegEx.  To be specific, I am looking for a RegEx to match for the value following the identifier and equals sign but before the semi-colon.

Can someone provide me with a detailed example so I can learn how to use the lookahead assertion (if that is the best way to do something like this)?

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: why do you think you need a lookahead for this?  A lookahead would be for something like identifying the `int a` part in `int a=5` vs `int a;`.  You'd be "looking ahead" to see if there is an assignment or not.

Comment: my lack of knowledge in the realm of lookaheads is showing... You bring up an interesting case that I will actually find useful.  How would I use a lookahead to see if the variable has been declared on not like you mentioned?

Comment: something like `/int\s+(\w+)\s*(?==\s*\d+\s*)/`.  Basically it only matches `int a` if it's declared (using `=#`)

Comment: can you break that expression down for me so I can better understand what it is doing?  possibly chat might be easier?

Comment: `int` + `\s+` (whitespace) + `(\w+)` (variable name) + `\s*` (whitespace) + `(?=` (start of look-ahead) + `=` + `\s*` (whitespace) + `\d+` (digits) + `\s*` (whitespace) + `)` (end of lookahead).  Basically it matches `int <name> = <number>` with whatever whitespace you throw in.  The `= <number>` part is in a look-ahead meaning it isn't actually matched in the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `/=\s*(\d+)\s*;/` would be best, since it allows for arbitrary numbers of spaces between the elements, and captures the digits. In the returned array, `[1]` will be the number.

Comment: @Joey, seems you don't know anything about arrays. I suggest you read up on those.

Comment: @Joey Wint a = 5;".match(/=\s*(\d+)\s*;/); yields ["5", "5"] result 0 is always the complete match. Then capture groups start in 1

Comment: @Joey I made a Typo I mean to write: `"int a = 5;".match(/=\s*(\d+)\s*;/);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the look-ahead with the following snippet:

```
var input = "a = 12345;"
var inputValue = input.replace(/\w+\s*=\s*(\d+)\s*(?=;).*/, "$1");
```

in the example result is 12345 using `"a = 5;"` gives 5